# Nuget Manager can't read from subfolders

Tags: c#, nuget, repository, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I've setup a private NuGet repository on a network folder (eg. `\\networkfolder\nugetfeed\`) but my Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019 cannot read packages nested in subfolders in that repository. Eg. I've generated a new folder tree for a package testlib1.0.0.nupkg and it looks like:

testlib:

- 1.0.0:

  - lib
  - testlib1.0.0.nupkg
  - testlib1.0.0.nupkg.sha512
  - testlib.nuspec

I then uploaded this whole folder to the remote repository and PM cannot find it. When I put the testlib1.0.0.nupkg file into the root folder in the repository, PM can see it without any problems.
I also created a local repository (eg. c:\nugetLocalFeed) and added it to my VS and PM can now read packages from subfolders without any problem. I also checked my folder access privileges on the shared drive. I am ale to create and read folder using Windows's file explorer and I run VS on the same account, with the same rights (and I run it as Admin).

Why is the NuGet Package Manager having problems reading packages from subfolders on the remote repository?

Comment: Did you configure the Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources? And add the related Package sources for the subfolders, and try to switch to this package source while installing your NuGet package?

Comment: "add the related Package sources for the subfolders" - what do you mean by that? that for every package I need to add its subfolders as a new package feed? I don't think that's how a package repository is supposed to work.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a potential issue. I also get the same result, I think we need to report this issue to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).